# Auto Dialing phone number extension in email signature?

Tags: android, iphone, email

I created a simple HTML eSignature with my company's main phone number and an extension. When I email the signature, both iPhone and Android devices can pick up the phone number itself and dial it through the phone app, but it doesn't pick up the extension. Based on other threads I've read, I've tried the following things:

```
<a href = "tel:1234567890pp509">Number here</a>

<a href = "tel:1234567890,509">Number here</a>

<a href = "tel:1234567890;509">Number here</a>

<a href = "tel:1234567890x509">Number here</a>
```

I do not know much at ALL about backend development for Android or iOs platforms or apps, let alone getting that code to cooperate with email clients. I've seen stuff about textview, autolink, etc...but I am so lost and don't know where to start.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848721/how-to-construct-a-telephone-number-link-on-android-that-includes-an-extension), I would recommend the comma method. It acts as a wait command that will give the phone enough time to get connected with the primary number before attempting the extension. Three commas is often considered the magic number. Let is know if that works for you, or if you're interested in a more theoretical explanation.

Example:

```
<a href = "tel:1234567890,,,509">Number here</a>
```

Comment: Another facet of this problem/solution: http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57559205-285/automatically-dial-extensions-for-android-contacts/