# How to incorporate auto dial in android phone using js?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ivr

I have been trying to implement auto dial through the below code:
document.location ="tel:+122222222 ,, *!2345" , where  +22222222 is the telephone number and the *!2345 represents the code that needs to be auto dialed.
This functionality worked perfectly for ios and windows ,but failed in android. I saw in some blogs stating that android does not support "," instead uses "p" for pause . But when I tried using "p" , it is getting converted to "7".

I want to incorporate same dial in functionality for android.

Comment: Please check this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774243/can-i-make-a-phone-call-from-html-on-android

Comment: The telephone functionality works.It correctly dials to the number.But the second part gets terminated when a comma is encountered.

Comment: You can find another version of your question here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848721/how-to-construct-a-telephone-number-link-on-android-that-includes-an-extension

Comment: The above link is not useful

Comment: Is there any solution for the above ?